# ssh does not use db_home in cygwin

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I am new to cygwin and I want to use cygwin as a ssh client, among other things. I've already a `.ssh` folder including the `config`. Now I want to reuse the existing `.ssh` folder in cygwin. So I copied the existing `.ssh` folder to `/home/%U`. But the problem is, that ssh does not respect the directory defined in `/etc/profile/nsswitch.conf`. It always uses the `C:\Users\<username>` directory, which is set from our administrator as `USERPROFILE` environment variable.

How can I tell ssh to use the config of the folder defined via `db_home` property?

My configuration looks as follows:

**/etc/nsswitch.conf**

```sh
$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
#    This file is read once by the first process in a Cygwin process tree.
#    To pick up changes, restart all Cygwin processes.  For a description
#    see https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-nsswitch
#
# Defaults:
# passwd:   files db
# group:    files db
# db_enum:  cache builtin
db_home:  /home/%U
# db_shell: /bin/bash
# db_gecos: <empty>
```

**/etc/profile (adjusted according to this [post](https://superuser.com/a/603768))**

```sh
$ cat /etc/profile | grep -C 10 "Set the user id"
        PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"
    else
        PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"
    fi
  fi

# see https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2014-05/msg00352.html
# MANPATH="/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man${MANPATH:+:${MANPATH}}"
  INFOPATH="/usr/local/info:/usr/share/info:/usr/info${INFOPATH:+:${INFOPATH}}"

  # Set the user id
  USER="$(id -un)"

  # Set user home dir
  HOME=$(eval echo "~$USER")

  # TMP and TEMP as defined in the Windows environment
  # can have unexpected consequences for cygwin apps, so we define
  # our own to match GNU/Linux behaviour.
  unset TMP TEMP
  TMP="/tmp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution by simply installing the `openssh` package in cygwin.

Found [here](https://superuser.com/a/1545122).